# Adjektiv für das Wort »Universität«

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

Wenn ich über etwas spreche, das irgendwie einen *allgemeinen* Bezug auf die Universität hat (also nicht einzige Universität, sondern das Konzept): Gibt es dafür ein Adjektiv wie *universitätisch,* das man z. B. wie folgt verwenden kann?

> Ich finde den *universitätischen* Alltag anstrengend.

In meiner Muttersprache gibt es eines; vielleicht fehlt es mir deswegen im Deutschen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Man kann das Folgende sagen:

> Ich finde **den universitären** Alltag anstrengend.

Ein paar Ergebnisse aus der [Google-Suche](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22den+universit%C3%A4ren+Alltag%22&start=0) für "den universitären Alltag":

> Das Ziel ist es, behinderten Studierenden den **universitären** Alltag zu erleichtern.
>
> ... sowie mündliche und schriftliche Kommunikationsformen für den **universitären** Alltag werden trainiert.

Answer (score 12):

> [**universitär**](http://www.duden.de/node/661566/revisions/1233079/view)
>   <Adjektiv> *die Universität betreffend, zu ihr gehörend:*
>   universitäre Einrichtungen